# Instr returns 0 Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The first Instr() function gives me a zero even though the substring is clearly within the string as I have checked on Yahoos website. Please help me.

```
Sub ImportBPlans()
Dim BPlan As String, FullHTML As String, URL1 As String, Cut1 As String,  T1   As String
Dim FO As Integer, LO As Integer

For i = 2 To LastRow

    T1 = WB1.Cells(i, 1).Value



    URL1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=" + T1 + "+Profile"
    FullHTML = GetHTML(URL1)
    BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
    x = Len(FullHTML)

    FO = InStr(1, FullHTML, BPlan, vbTextCompare) + Len(BPlan)
    LO = InStr(FO, FullHTML, "<")
    Cut1 = Left(FullHTML, LO)
    Cut1 = Right(Cut1, FO - LO)
    WB5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cut1

Next i


End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim htmlBDY As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        GetHTML = htmlBDY.body.outerHTML
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the sample of FullHTML where the BPlan value is?

Comment: Okay
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=AAPL+Profile

Comment: yes that is my question that I solved, and now I have a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've had trouble doing what your trying. It seems that either MSHTML or MSXTML or both modify the raw HTML, which makes parsing it an "adventure". To get your code to work I modified your line:

```
BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
```

to

```
BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></tbody></table>" & vbCrLf & "<p>"
```

Where did the extra `</tbody>` and `vbCrLf` come from? Dunno. I don't see them when I look at the raw HTML source with a browser, but they are definitely in `FullHTML`. Bob Dole's `BPlan` seems like it should have worked --- doing a browser FIND on the source HTML for Dole's `BPlan` succeeds. If someone can explain this, and knows how to reliably parse HTML with these tools, I'd love to learn!

Answer (score 1):

What i had to do to get this to run and update was change the FO and LO to data type long because the location was greater than the maximum value of an integer variable.

```
Sub ImportBPlans()
Dim BPlan As String, FullHTML As String, URL1 As String, Cut1 As String,  T1   As String
Dim FO As Long, LO As Long

For i = 2 To LastRow

    T1 = WB1.Cells(i, 1).Value



    URL1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=" + T1 + "+Profile"
    FullHTML = GetHTML(URL1)
    BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
    x = Len(FullHTML)

    FO = InStr(1, FullHTML, BPlan, vbTextCompare) + Len(BPlan)
    LO = InStr(FO, FullHTML, "<")
    Cut1 = Left(FullHTML, LO)
    Cut1 = Right(Cut1, FO - LO)
    WB5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cut1

Next i


End Sub
```